# Can I install Schluter trim on alcove edge the day before tiling?

Tags: shower, tile, tiling, kerdi

Hello – and thanks to everyone here for the helpful posts over the years! I’m tiling a tub/shower alcove with 6x12 subway tile. The alcove will end with Schluter Rondec. I’m a small-time framer and remodeler and have never tiled before, but I’ve prepared… a lot (the walls are even flat and plumb haha).

*Question: Can I install the Rondec trim profile one day, let it dry, then come back and tile later? *

This JB thread – https://www.johnbridge.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=115183 – advises against it… somewhat. And every video I’ve found shows tiling immediately after installing trim. But there is no way I’ll be able to tile up an 8’ H valve wall with 6” H tile before the thinset on the Rondec hardens. I also just want to take my time… I’m a tradesperson so I know to take new things slow. But I want to follow best practices here too. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would prefer to add trim at the end of tiling.  The measurements and installation would need to be perfect to make sure tile fits to the trim.  With the trim placed after, if the tiles are a tiny bit short or long, will not matter, just add the trim to match.

Comment: My thought was to install the trim perfectly plumb, then tile *starting at* the trim, back toward the inside corners of the shower (and cut the tiles to be perfect back in those inside corners... which I'd do by measuring at each row, not just with math).